# TestNG @Factory with @Dataprovider

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, testng

So, I`m trying to make my testsuite run each test case for multiple credentials.

Hence, I defined a Data provider which would provide @Factory the credentials to run the test multiple times against each credential.

My code is the following:

```
package TestSuite.TP_LogOut;

import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Factory;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import Repository.URLs;
import SeLib.CompareURL;
import SeLib.LogIn;
import SeLib.WaitAndClick;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class TC_LogOut{

    @BeforeTest
    public void beforeTest() throws InterruptedException{
        Reporter.log("The test has just begun.");
    }

    private WebDriver driver;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @Factory (dataProvider="credentials")
    public setter(String username, String password){
        this.username=username;
        this.password = password;
        System.out.println("Credentials "+username+" "+password);
    }
    @DataProvider
    public static Object[][] credentials() {
        return new Object[][]   { {     "id1",  "pass1"  },
                                  {     "id2",  "pass2"  } };
    }
    @Test
    public void TC_LogIn() throws Exception{

        // use username, password here:
        LogIn.Execute(driver, username, password);
    }
}
```

For some reason, @Factory does not admit a non-return type like in several examples that I saw, and points me out that it should be a void type function.

Is there any apparent solution which does not imply @Factory to create multiple test case instances?

If there isn`t, how should the return type be?

Thank you ...

EDIT: Since I am calling the log-in function inside the test case, by passing the driver to the LogIn.Execute method, I thought that it would be a great idea just for LogIn to handle running the multiple Test Cases and then it would just make it simpler, not having to maintain the @Factory and @DataProvider in each Test Case. But this would be like an incorrect programming setup, wouldn`t it be?

Comment: @Factory normally applied to class constructor. But you are tagging with method. So that it is expecting the return type. If you change the method name setter with class name TC_LogOut, it may work. but you need to resolve the driver object. We can tag Factory to method but you need to set return type as object arrary like object[].

Answer (score 1):

The best solution was just to use @DataProvider without @Factory, for the method, such as:

```
   @DataProvider
    public static Object[][] credentials() {
        return new Object[][]   { {     "id1",  "pass1"  },
                                  {     "id2",  "pass2"  } };
    }
    @Test
    public void TC_LogIn(String username, String password) throws Exception{
```